# spoj - opn - transform the expression - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

first time i am trying to submit solution on spoj , 
this is my solution for solving the [transform the expression problem on spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/).I am getting the SIGSEV error which is a runtime error  , segmentation fault . 
I have checked a lot in my code , but i dont see any such kind of error in my code .
Plz help solving this .

I HAVE THE EDITED CODE :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int precedence(char c)
{
switch (c)
{
    case '/':
        return 2;

    case '*':
        return 2;

    case '+':
        return 1;

    case '-':
        return 1;

    case '^':
        return 3;

    case ')':
        return 4;

    case '(':
        return -1;

    default:
        return -1 ;
}
}

int main()
{
 //char input[400]="a*(b+c)-d/e";
 // char input[400]="a+b*c-d/e*f";
 // char input[400] = "(a+b*c-d)/(e*f)";
 // char input[400] = "(a+(b*c))" ;
 //char input[400] = "((a+b)*(z+x))";
 // char input[400] = "((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))";
 char input[402];
 char *stack;
 char *output;
 char *p = input ;
 int i , top  , t  , l ;


scanf("%d",&t);


while (t-- != 0 )
{
    scanf("%s",input);
    p = input ;
    i = 0 ;
    top = 0 ;
    l = strlen(input);
    stack = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(input)));
    output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(input)));


    stack[top++]='(';

    *(p+l)=')';
    *(p+l+1)= '\0';


    while(p[0] != '\0')
    {
        if (p[0] >= 'a' && p[0] <= 'z' )
        {
            output[i]=p[0];
            i++;
        }
        else if (p[0] == '(')
        {
            stack[top++] = p[0];
        }
        else if (p[0] == ')')
        {
            while (stack[top-1] != '(')
            {
                --top;
                output[i] = stack[top];

                i++ ;
            }
            //to remove the left parenthesis
            top--;

        }
        else if (p[0] == '+' || p[0] == '-' || p[0] == '*' || p[0] == '/' || p[0]=='^')
        {
            while(precedence(stack[top-1]) >= precedence(p[0]))
            {
                output[i]=stack[top-1];
                top--;
                i++;
                //j = k;
            }
            stack[top] = p[0];
            top++;
        }

        p++;
    }
    printf("%s\n",output);
    free(stack);
    free(output);

for(i = (strlen(input)-1) ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    input[i]='\0';


}

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Your precedences are wrong, `^` has higher precedence than `*` and `/`.

Comment: Unrelated, but shouldn't the power/exponentiation operator (`^`) have a higher precedence than that of multiplication and division?

Comment: `length <= 400` means you need at least 401 bytes for `input`. Remember the 0-terminator.

Comment: And you have tried running in a debugger to see _where_ the crash is?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Sir , I agree that `^` is exponention but  I dint find  such operator except the XOR operator .. that why I made it a XOR operator ...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : I ran the code in a debugger , i dint crash ..:(

Comment: @CodeJack Regardless of what it stands for, the operators are explicitly listed "priority from the lowest to the highest".

Comment: @DanielFischer : Sir , what should be the precedence of `(` , `)` , `^` ??

Comment: You have 1 for addition/subtraction, and 2 for multiplication/division, so exponentiation could have 3, and parentheses 4.

Comment: Sir , if I keep precedence of `(` and `)` , the problem does not solve

Comment: You need `'('` to have the least precedence in order to stop popping off the stack, I think (Note, I haven't checked that the algorithm is correct, I assume that here for the sake of argument). You never push a `')'` on the stack, so what you return for that doesn't matter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28170/discussion-between-codejack-and-daniel-fischer)

Comment: Debuggers typically clears all variables, so if crashes when run normally but not in the debugger it can indicate you are using an uninitialized variable (likely a pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*(p+strlen(p))=')';
```

overwrites the 0-terminator of `p`, then

```
*(p+strlen(p))= '\0';
```

the `strlen(p)` in this may not find any 0-terminator anymore, and cause a segfault. Also, that line is superfluous anyway, `*(p + strlen(p))` is already 0 by the definition of `strlen` (if `p` is a string, i.e. 0-terminated).

If you want to add a `')'` at the end, store the length,

```
size_t len = strlen(p);
p[len] = ')';
p[len+1] = 0;
```

and use that twice. **But make sure that you have enough space allocated.**

Comment: Sir , now I have used an int variable and done `*(p+l)='('` and `*(p+l+1)='\0'`...right ??

Comment: I suppose the `'('` was a typo and you meant `')'`. Yes, here there's no danger that `int` is too small, and whether you write `*(p+l)` or `p[l]` is a matter of taste. And of course, a) `input` must be larger, and b) `malloc(sizeof(strlen(input)));` is too short. If you add parentheses, you need at least `streln(p) + 3` (two for the parentheses, one for the 0-terminator.

Comment: i guess you are trying to say that i must use size of input as 403 instead of 401 , but i think it should be 402 instead of 403 beacuse 400+')'+'\0'

Comment: Ah, right, you let `p` point to `input`. Yes, 402 is enough, I thought you'd put the opening paren into `p` too, but you put that on the stack. I haven't followed the logic, so it may be that less would be sufficient for `stack` and `output`, but memory isn't _so_ scarce, so why not just add sufficient space, say 420 for all of them?